# How to avoid Git getting installed for every git operation in Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I started exploring Jenkins with GitHub, Ant and Maven. According to the video posted on youtube [Jenkin-GitHub-Ant-Maven](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTQGi5jzjvo), I followed everything.

But, when I give the repository URL, a Git Installation window opens. When I click Yes, it takes me to install Git. I have to do this twice. After that, when I starting building the job, its showing the Git Installation window for every git operation performed to get the code from GitHub repository and it keeps on installing.

Can you please help me in not installing Git everytime?

**Edited: Added more info.**

I am using Windows 8 OS, deployed on Tomcat 7. In Configure systems page, I gave the value as git.exe for the GIT column. Error shown that the git.exe was not found in PATH variables. So, I created a folder and placed the git.exe file and then added the folder in PATH variables. Then it accepted without any errors. Would this be the reason for doing the installation again and again for every git operation? I have no clue on what is happening.

Comment: What is your OS? What's in the PATH variable?

Comment: @NickVolynkin I am using Windows 8 and I have given the git entry as "C:\Techie\Tools\git" in the path variable. The file git.exe is located int the above folder. Git is already installed in the following path "C:\Apps\Git".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using Windows 8 and I have given the git entry as "C:\Techie\Tools\git" in the path variable. The file git.exe is located int the above folder. Git is already installed in the following path "C:\Apps\Git".

Do I understand you right, that

1. Git is installed to "C:\Apps\Git"
2. PATH includes "C:\Techie\Tools\git" and doesn't include "C:\Apps\Git"
3. "C:\Techie\Tools\git" only has git.exe and not other git files?

If all above is true, this is what happens.

1. Any attempt to launch git resolves as "C:\Techie\Tools\git\git.exe" which is not a valid git installation.
2. You then reinstall git to "C:\Apps\Git"
3. Nothing changes for the system.

To solve this on next installation pick option 2 on next installation. And remove "C:\Techie\Tools\git\git.exe" from PATH.

[image]

Comment: I did what you said. It working fine, meaning it does not show the Git installation window for every git action. But, I am getting the mvn.bat not  found. Attached the log. The Maven in located inside C:\Techie\apache-maven\bin and same is added in the PATH variables. When I type mvn command in CMD, I see the maven project startup., which means the maven is available in the path. But the error I get in Jenkins, looks like it is not available for Jenkins. Log is added as a separate comment because of insufficient space

Comment: ---- ERROR LOG --- [test-build-2] $ cmd.exe /C '"mvn.bat -f String-replacer compile && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
'mvn.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Glad that this helped. For maven please make a new question. I'm not enough proficient with jenkins, maven & windows to help here.